# GitHub Actions not working when deleting file

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a GitHub Actions workflow like:

```
name: foobar
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
    paths:
      - 'routes/**'
      - '.github/**'
  pull_request:
    paths:
      - 'routes/**'
jobs: ...
```

What intrigues me is that when I add some file to routes/ it triggers the action but not when I only delete some file inside routes.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, please consider using the [dorny/paths-filter](https://github.com/dorny/paths-filter) GitHub Action that is able to "Consider if file was added, modified or deleted" (See the advanced option [here](https://github.com/dorny/paths-filter#advanced-options)) like:

```
- uses: dorny/paths-filter@v2
      id: filter
      with:
        # Changed file can be 'added', 'modified', or 'deleted'.
        # By default, the type of change is not considered.
        # Optionally, it's possible to specify it using nested
        # dictionary, where the type of change composes the key.
        # Multiple change types can be specified using `|` as the delimiter.
        filters: |
          shared: &shared
            - common/**
            - config/**
          addedOrModified:
            - added|modified: '**'
          allChanges:
            - added|deleted|modified: '**'
          addedOrModifiedAnchors:
            - added|modified: *shared
```

This approach will require an extra job that will prevent the execution in case.